# How to count files, directories and symbolic links recursively in a directory excluding hidden files?

Tags: shell, count

How can I count files, directories and symbolic links recursively in a directory excluding hidden files?

Comment: Please explicitely give target OS ? Context hints it's a Unix question (reference to symbolic links and shell) but it would be better if stated explicitely. As it looks like homework there may also exists some programming constraints.

Answer (score 0):

```
find DIRECTORY -xdev ! -path "*/.*" -ls |
awk '{print $3}' |
cut -b 1         |
sort             |
uniq -c
```

Explanation:

1. Find all files in DIRECTORY with no hidden elements on its path
2. Take third column (file type and permissions)
3. Take first caracter (file type)
4. Sort caracters
5. Count them

**-xdev** avoids find following symbolic links into a filesystem different from DIRECTORY. If you want to count files pointed by symbolic links in different filesystems, remove it, but beware of [circular links](https://serverfault.com/q/265598/268651).

This will show something like this:

```
15489 -
 2749 d
    4 l
```

where '-' means regular files, 'd' directories and 'l' symbolic links.